# abstract class with default constructor and class with private constructor difference

Tags: java, abstract-class, private-constructor

what's the difference between an Abstract class with a default constructor and a class with private constructor?

I also have another doubt ,
consider this program below. Can anyone please explain me.Does such code have any use ?

```
abstract class AbstractAndPrivate 
{
AbstractAndPrivate()
{
     AbstractAndPrivate ref= new AbstractAndPrivate(1) {

        @Override
        int m2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
        }
                    };  

            }
void m1()
{
    System.out.println("m1() accessed");
}
abstract int m2();

AbstractAndPrivate(int a)
{

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.print("hello ");

 AbstractAndPrivate ref= new AbstractAndPrivate() {public int m2(){return 1;}}; 
 System.out.println(ref);
 ref.m1();
 ref.m2();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what's the difference between an Abstract class with a default constructor and a class with private constructor?

If there's a default constructor, it will be callable from subclasses. If it's *private*, you'll only be able to create subclasses within the same class, as that's the only context in which the private constructor will be accessible.

Note that the code you've provided is *neither* of these situations - it's *explicitly* providing a package-protected parameterless constructor. That's not private, and it's not a default constructor.

Whether the class is abstract or not is orthogonal to the constructors it provides, although an abstract class with only a private constructor forces you to create *subclasses* within the declaring class in order to create instances, rather than just relying on you creating *instances* within the declaring class.

Answer (score 0):

also, abstract class can have an *abstract method*, that needs to be implemented by subclasses (unless they're abstract too)

**EDIT**: -1? come on, abstract methods are also sort of explains the logical difference between abstract classes and classes with private constructor. please...